# rails - list of tenants to migrate appears to be empty when loading a schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

what does it mean if in rails I run db:schema:load, and the schema loads until it says that "the list of tenants to migrate appears to be empty"?
And what ways are available to solve this?

As in here (sorry I am unable to format it better):

> ...
>
> --create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.4490s
>
> -- create_table("web_migrations", {:id=>false, :force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.6138s
>
> -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
>   -> 0.0332s
>
> [WARNING] - The list of tenants to migrate appears to be empty. This could mean a few things:
>
> ```
>       1. You may not have created any, in which case you can ignore this message
>       2. You've run `apartment:migrate` directly without loading the Rails environment
>         * `apartment:migrate` is now deprecated. Tenants will automatically be migrated with `db:migrate`
>
>     Note that your tenants currently haven't been migrated. You'll need to run `db:migrate` to rectify this.
> ```

I noticed that maybe db:schema:load runs twice?
It starts fine:

> -- create_table("asset_status", {:force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.5029s
>
> -- create_table("asset_type", {:force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.2904s
>
> [continues...]
>
> -- create_table("web_migrations", {:id=>false, :force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.3347s
>
> -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()    -> 1.1729s

and after this again:

> -- create_table("asset_status", {:force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.6400s
>
> -- create_table("asset_type", {:force=>:cascade})
>   -> 0.5805s
>
> [continues...]

is it wrong?

Comment: Do you have outstanding migrations to run?  "rake db:migrate" ?

Comment: Hi @Ilan Yes, I am coming from there. If I write "rake db:migrate" it tells me the same message. And it is an error that I cannot decipher, so I cannot trace back the problem

Comment: I found the same thing, that's just apartment telling it wasn't configure to migrate anything, but it's ok. I haven't figure out yet how to prevent the message from showing

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps someone in future, You can use single tenant migration in-case there is no other solution.

Run `DB=tenant_name rake db:migrate`

This will migrate the database for a specific tenant.